# jQuery fade in and fade out loop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, optimization

I am making a results screen which toggles between showing the user their best time/score and their latest time/score. I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295489/continuous-loop-of-fade-in-out-function) using this site but after leaving the website open for a few hours I saw that the timings had gone out of sync. I know that this is hard to test so I thought I would see if any experts on here could help me to optimize or fix my code.

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/GvFtf)
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nR29c/)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval( function() { resultsTransition(); }, 4000);

  function resultsTransition() {
    $('.latest-transition').fadeOut(500).delay(3500).fadeIn(500).delay(3500);
    $('.best-transition').fadeIn(500).delay(3500).fadeOut(500).delay(3500);
  }
});
```

Comment: Provide more description because your present description isnt giving me any idea of what you are asking to solve

Comment: This does only load on the results page at the end of a level

Comment: Your animations take longer to complete than the duration of the interval. I wouldn't count on jquerys animations taking exactly the amount of time you specified as the interval, so you're bound to get into trouble at some point

Comment: I see that now @ReinderWit, I am fairly new to jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your design could be improved (and the out-of-sync problem solved) by simply toggling the opacity of the elements in your `resultsTransition` method instead of starting a new sequence, which could interfere unpredictably with the interval.

Something like:

```
var latestTransitionElementVisible = true; //the initial state of your elements

setInterval(resultsTransition, 4000); //note you can just pass the function name

function resultsTransition() {
    $('.latest-transition').fadeTo(500, latestTransitionElementVisible ? 0 : 1);
    $('.best-transition').fadeTo(500, latestTransitionElementVisible ? 1 : 0);
    latestTransitionElementVisible = !latestTransitionElementVisible ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess whatever problem/issue you are facing is because of varying animation times .Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout( function() { resultsTransition(); }, 4000);

  function resultsTransition() {
    if(!$('.latest-transition').is(':animated') && !$('.best-transition').is(':animated'))
    {
    $('.latest-transition').fadeOut(500).delay(3500).fadeIn(500).delay(3500);
    $('.best-transition').fadeIn(500).delay(3500).fadeOut(500).delay(3500);
    setTimeout( function() { resultsTransition(); }, 4000);
    }
  }
});
```